# Construction of Permutation Group (bounded order) from a Set of Permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, algorithms, computer-science

Given a set of permutation $S$. It has $|S|$ (The [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) of $S$) elements.
 Consider a subset $A\subset S$. We can construct a group using $A$.

One possible algorithm could be-

1. We start copying elements of $A$ to $B$, so $B=A$.
2. Construct all  possible [product (Composition of permutations–the group product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28mathematics%29)) of elements of $B$. There will be ${|B|}^{|B|}$ products.
3. If there is a new element (a new permutation), include that into set $B$ and repeat step $2$.
4. Else, there is no new element,Stop.
5. Construct $B^{-1}$ for set $B$.
6. The group is $G$,where  $G=B^{-1} \cup B$ ([see Generating set of a group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group)).

**Question:**

Does there always exist  a subset  $A$ of $S$ such that $G$ is a nontrivial group and $|G| \leq  |S|^{c} $ where $c$ is a constant?

### Edit:

Both $|S| , |A| > $ 1 , . The summary of the question: Is there  a group $G$,  where   $|G| \leq  |S|^{c} $ , $c$ is a constant and $G$ is constructed from $S$ as described above. For example, if $c=1, then |G| \leq  |S| $.

Comment: I am struggling to understand this question, but the answer seems to be no, because we could have $|S|=1$. I think you have $G = \langle A \rangle$ the subgroup generated by $A$, so why not just say that. Your algorithm is not very efficient!

Comment: @DerekHolt ,  both $|S| , |A|  > $ 1 (sorry for not writing that up), . The summary of the question: Is there  a group $G$,  where   $|G| \leq  |S|^{c} $ , $c$ is a constant and $G$ is constructed from $S$ as described above. For example, if $c=1, then |G| \leq  |S| $.

Comment: To D. Holt: you are correct. $G=<A>$.

Comment: I don't think so! Let $c$ be yiour constant, and choose a prime $p > 2^c$. let $H$ be a group of order $p$ and choose $S$ to consist of any two distinct elements of $H$. Then the only possibility for $G$ is $G=H$.

Comment: @DerekHolt ,  Lets call  that $P$ group (Sylow ) of order $p \geq 2^{c}$  and we  ensure  that there is no such element of you described  $P$ group in $S$, is that a sufficient condition?  would you please  suggest  researcher/ book  regarding  this problem?

Comment: @DerekHolt , I have a different question (not related to above post), if you have time, please reply : $S_n$ is  a symmetric group acting on $n$ objects. Does their exist a subgroup of $S_n$, say $G$ which is isomorphic  to a symmetric group and where $|G| = n^2 -1$?  I think , it is not possible for all $n$ , would you please comment.

Comment: @DerekHolt , this is Brocards problem, I was trying to see from group th POV. Probably, it may help.